# Chrome - debug WebGL crashing ("Rats! WebGL hit a snag.")

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, webgl

Our company recently upgraded our PC's to Windows 10, and ever since then we've constantly been getting the "Rats! WebGL hit a snag." message when browsing our website. We might normally brush this off as an internal network/pc issue, but this error only occurs on our own website. Browsing other websites does not cause this error. We're therefore concerned that some of our users out there might be experiencing this as well.

We don't use WebGL to my knowledge, and `document.querySelectorAll('canvas')` doesn't find any elements.

Is it possible to debug this to find the cause of the crash?

**Update**

It is a third party script that's trying to use WebGL, but it's pretty innocent and shouldn't be a problem. Now the question is, how can I determine why the following code causes a crash on our website?

```
let canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
canvas.getContext('webgl');
```

Comment: A canvas element might be created on the fly, but not added to document, to use for image export or something similar.  Also, if you haven't vetted all third party libs carefully, consider that there could be a small risk that some 3d party library is doing something buggy, or outright nefarious.

Comment: @visibleman It is indeed a third party script we use for fraud detection that's creating the element in JS. It only seems to break on our website though. I visited other sites that also load this script and it doesn't cause this crash. It's an interesting bug..

Comment: Without more information about the library and what it is doing with the canvas, it is difficult to tell.  The only thing I can think of at this point is to make sure that the 3d party script is not initiated twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add

```
HTMLCanvasElement.prototype.getContext = (function(origFn) {
  return function(...args) {
    debugger;
    return origFn.call(this, ...args);
  };
}(HTMLCanvasElement.prototype.getContext));
```

To the top of your page then open the debugger and see where it breaks?

Comment: Nice idea! I was able to verify with this that there is a third party script calling this, and that's when it breaks. Now I have to figure out why this only breaks when running on our domain, but not when the same code is run on others